# The phrase "the reason has to be because XXX"

Tags: phrases, expressions

> Husband asked, "Do you think it's true that men use 15,000 words a
>   day  and women use double?"
>
> The wife replied, "I think so, **The reason has to be because** we
>   have to repeat everything to men."

**Is "the reason has to be because" a common usage in colloquial conversations?**

Another question!

Does "A have to be B" mean the strong guess(A must be B or I'm sure A is B)?

I learned "the reason is because S+V" is grammatically wrong (although many people use it) as far as I remember my SAT writing class materials correctly.

Comment: With regard to your second question, "have to be" = "must be." At face value, it expresses certainty, not merely high probability; but both "have to be" and "must be" are frequently used in exaggeration or hyperbole.

Answer (score 0):

**Is "the reason has to be because" a common usage in colloquial conversations?**

It may be a common usage, but it's ungrammatical. *Because* is used between two propositions, to justify the first as a result of the truth of the second - *I went to London because I wanted to visit X* or *She is not a good guitarist because she hardly ever practises*.

*The reason has to be* is not a complete proposition.

To be properly grammatical, the sentence should be  should be written as *The reason has to be **that**...*, or alternatively *Women use double **because**...*

But there's nothing wrong with *The reason has to be* as a phrase. You could replace *has to* with *must* but it wouldn't alter the meaning.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any wrong to this sentence.   There are several ways to express it. Here are two of them:

1.The reason is that we have to repeat everything to men.
2. The reason has to be **for that you are talking me about** because we have to repeat everything to men.

```
for that you are talking me about - this part of speech is meant by. 
I hope it helps.
```